# Is the current msgraph-sdk-java ready to be used for production level applications

Tags: java, api, sdk, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am creating an application which will fetch different tenants' user details, oneDrive files and sharepoint files. I am using MSGraph APIs for doing the same. I want to use the sdk provided for the same for the ease of getting and handling data. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

I would require batching, delta APIs, filtering etc.

Is the current msgraph-sdk-java developed enough to be used for a production level application ??

I am just worried because it says that the current version in in preview version
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/blogs/microsoft-graph-java-sdk-preview-2/

Comment: It is GA and therefore we consider the code that is there to be stable.  However, not all the features that you are looking for are there yet.  We are currently working on batching.  You can make delta queries but we will be doing more to make it easier soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just worried because it says that the current version in in
>   preview version
>   https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/blogs/microsoft-graph-java-sdk-preview-2/

You're looking at an old link probably (at least seems that way by the link mentioned as part of your question.)

Check out the release notes and current version, it looks like it went into GA in September 2018.

Please refer here:

1. [Java GA - September 2018](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/releases/tag/1.0.0)

[image]

2. [Microsoft Graph SDK for Java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/tree/master)

   [image]
3. [Microsoft Graph SDK Release Notes for September 2018](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-sdk-release-notes-sept-2018/)

Comment: Yeah I think I missed the release notes. Thanks !!